# IE8 and .val problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a problem with IE8 and my function. My function works fine in other browsers, but as usual IE8 is being a pain. Some boxes will be filled in while others won't be. I have checked my hash to make sure there was a value there, and the value is defined. IE8 is just choosing not to fill in some inputs. Any idea what the problem might be?

```
var fillTemplate = function(jsonResponse) {
        periods = jsonResponse['#input_periods'];
        generatePeriodInput();
        var $this = $(this);


        $.each(jsonResponse, function(key, value) {
            $(key).val(value);
        });
    }
```

Comment: i think key, value is backwards, and is that css selector really in your JSON response?

Comment: Can you give an example of what jsonResponse contains? Also, are you using a version of jQuery prior to 2.0? Version 2.0 removed support for older versions of IE.

Comment: I checked the values of key and value and they are both correct, in every browser. Yes that CSS selector is in my JSON response. It made it a bit easier to set elements.

Comment: I'm using Jquery 1.10.2. jsonResponse is just a hash containing a css selector, and it's value.

'#input_periods' => "5"

Comment: What does the dev console return? IE doesn't like certain var names (i.e. 'class')- try renaming 'periods' to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Thanks to adam_bear I was able to solve this problem. I had to rename some of my ids.